# Analyze pull requests using SonarCloud

Tags: c#, github, sonarqube, pull-request, sonar-runner

I want to use SonarQube to analyze **any** pull request (PR) made to my project.

Few quick points:

- My project is hosted on Github, it is public, is written in C#, and I'm using [Appveyor](https://www.appveyor.com) for continues integration (CI);
- I am using [SonarCloud](https://about.sonarcloud.io) (a public instance of [SonarQube](https://www.sonarqube.org)) for code quality check, and it already does a fantastic job analyzing **internal** PRs (i.e., the PRs made from main repository, e.g., merge `dev` branch on `master` branch);
- I want this to analyze external PRs (i.e., PRs made from arbitrary forks of my project), which is possible using [SonarQube Github plugin](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/GitHub+Plugin);
- and most importantly: *I am not gonna put my API keys on any public file, and Appveyor is not gonna expose my secured tokens on public PRs*.

Given these points, this is what I did:

- created a bot and gave it write access to my repo (as explained [here](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/GitHub+Plugin));
- on the sonarcloud and under `Administration -> Settings -> Pull Requests (Alpha)`, I set the `Authentication token` with the bot's token and set the `Repository identifier` with my repo address in the `<Organization>/<Repo>` format;
- Update the `appveyor.yml` file of my project so to run SonarQube analysis on all PRs; similar to the following:

```
build_script:
choco install "msbuild-sonarqube-runner" -y
MSBuild.SonarQube.Runner.exe begin /k:"REPO" /o:"ORGANIZATION" /d:"sonar.host.url=https://sonarcloud.io" /d:"sonar.analysis.mode=preview"
MSBuild.exe /t:Rebuild
MSBuild.SonarQube.Runner.exe end
```

However, still I don't see SonarQube using the bot to comment on new PRs (similar to [their demo](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/GitHub+Plugin).

Answer (score 1):

The feature you are trying to activate is not ready to be used yet - which is why it is named "Alpha" (`Administration -> Settings -> Pull Requests (Alpha)`).

In any case, even when this feature is ready, while this will secure your **GitHub token** because you will save it on SonarCloud only (which is great), you will still have to provide your **SonarCloud token** to perform the analysis. And as you don't want to unveil your SonarCloud token, you won't be able to analyze external pull requests. Unfortunately, we currently have no solution to solve this limitation.

Comment: CodeCov has a great solution for analyzing coverage on PRs without exposing API token: if the request is originated from _trusted_ CI services (e.g., Appveyor, Travis, and etc.), then the request will be processed without needing API key.

Comment: Another point, though it is good that you named the feature with `Alpha` postfix, but I would read it as _this is functional, but is subject to sever changes_. Therefore, it may not be a bad idea to clearly mention on top of this configuration tab that _it is not functional yet_.

Answer (score 0):

> I am not gonna put my API keys on any public file, and Appveyor is not
>   gonna expose my secured tokens on public PRs.

For solving this issue you can just encrypt the token in appveyor with https://ci.appveyor.com/tools/encrypt.

[image]

And copy paste that encrypted value into your appveyor.xml file.